# SVG not rendering as expected in chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, svg

Lately I've been experiencing some weird behavior in chrome where circles appear to have corners, making them look like rounded squares. I've attached an image as example.

[image: Circle example]

The corresponding code:

```
<circle class="hover" r="3.5999999999999996" cx="50" cy="50" fill="#539f00" opacity="0.8"></circle>
```

I have no idea what's causing this, as the element is clearly defined as a circle.

Comment: Can you paste all the code to make that instead of just the one circle?

Comment: @Charlie yea, the circle seems perfectly round to me. I have even tried transform and scaling the svg up, to see if it deforms anyhow, but it is still nicely sharp and round.

Comment: Looks a bit like the circle has been approximated using `c` or `q` curves. Quadratic curves especially will give you a pillow shape. It could be the svg optimizer thinks it is only going to be a tiny circle so can safely use a simpler algorithm. How are you scaling the SVG? (also I'm pretty sure you can round the radius to `3.6` with no discernible change.)